# C++: Registration of Global Variable Before Definition

Tags: c++, global-variables, undefined, local, bitset

I need a global variable in my C++ program. It is going to be a vector of bitsets. However, the size of the bitsets is determined at runtime by a function.

So basically, I would like to register the variable (in the top part of my code) and later define it properly by the function that determines the bitarrays' size.

Is there a way to do this in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `dynamic_bitset` from boost:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/dynamic_bitset.hpp>

std::vector< boost::dynamic_bitset<> > bitsets;

int main() {
    bitsets.push_back(boost::dynamic_bitset<>(1024));
    bitsets.push_back(boost::dynamic_bitset<>(2048));
    std::cout << bitsets[0].size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << bitsets[1].size() << std::endl;
}
```

You could also use a `vector<bool>` instead, i.e. `vector< vector<bool> >` for a vector of bitsets. It is specialized to only use one bit per element.

Comment: Indeed, I think I have to use a dynamic size solution, because I also return bitsets from functions, so I would need to know the size for the function definition as well. Thanks, I'll try the suggested Alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

bitsets sizes are fixed at compile time. just use `static vector<vector<bool>> MyGlobalBits;`